# Scala pattern matching - subset on list containing strings

Tags: scala

I want to subset on people's names whose surnames are in names.

The following isn't working

```
val names = List("Smith","Adams","Crawford")
val people =List("Billy Jean","Will Morten","Lenhardt Peterson","Lauryn Crawford","George Smith","Priscilla Adams")

people.filter(p=> names.exists(p.name.contains))
```

Comment: What you're doing here is not pattern matching. Read more at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html, and what is `p.name` anyway? That's a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surnames come in all sorts of confusing configurations.

```
val names = List("Smith","von Braun","Jones","de Kooning")
val people =List("Billy Jean","Will Morten","Lenhardt Peterson",
  "Lauryn Crawford","George Smith","Priscilla Adams",
  "Wernher von Braun", "Diederik Arnoldus De Beer", "Willem de Kooning")

names.flatMap(n => people.find(_.matches(s".* $n")))
// res0: List[String] = List(George Smith, Wernher von Braun, Willem de Kooning)
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive and not most effecient solution:

```
val names = Set("Smith","Adams","Crawford")
val people = List("Billy Jean","Will Morten",
                  "Lenhardt Peterson","Lauryn Crawford", 
                  "George Smith","Priscilla Adams")

people.filter(x => names.contains(x.split(" ").lastOption.getOrElse("")))
      .foreach(println)
```

Results in:

```
Lauryn Crawford
George Smith
Priscilla Adams
```